# Triple points for other substances

Tags: water, states-of-matter

Can substances other than H2O have a triple point, where the three usual phases of matter (solid/liquid/gas) can exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see this wikipedia entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point

which gives the example:

> the triple point of mercury occurs at a temperature of −38.8344 °C and a pressure of 0.2 mPa.

and furthermore provides a table of triple points of various common substances:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point#Table_of_triple_points